I have problems with utf 16 le bom encoding, the character that needs to be replaced is not replaced with the right one
I have the code:
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

 #define threads 64
 #define BUF_SIZE 2
   #define BOM_SIZE 2 // Size of BOM for UTF-16 LE

   // Global mutex
   HANDLE hMutex;
    
      // Structure for data exchange
      struct MYDATA {
        int num;
wchar_t file[MAX_PATH];
wchar_t replacement; // Replacement character
int replacementsCount; // Replacement counter
    } data[threads];

  // Thread function
    DWORD WINAPI threadfunc(LPVOID param) {
// Set console encoding to UTF-16 LE
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);

MYDATA* myData = (MYDATA*)param;
wchar_t* filename = myData->file;
wchar_t replacement = myData->replacement; // Replace space with the specified 
   character

HANDLE hIn = CreateFileW(filename, GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
if (hIn == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    wprintf(L"(Thread) Can't open file %s!\n", filename);
    return 0; // Move to the next file
}

wchar_t outputFilename[MAX_PATH];
wcscpy(outputFilename, filename);
wchar_t* pos = wcsrchr(outputFilename, L'.');
if (pos == NULL) {
    wcscat(outputFilename, L".out");
}
else {
    wcscpy(pos, L".out");
}

HANDLE hOut = CreateFileW(outputFilename, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, 
   FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
if (hOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    CloseHandle(hIn);
    wprintf(L"(Thread) Can't open output file %s!\n", outputFilename);
    return 0; // Move to the next file
}

// Write BOM to the output file
const CHAR bom[BOM_SIZE] = { 0xFF, 0xFE }; // BOM for UTF-16 LE
DWORD bytesWritten;
WriteFile(hOut, bom, BOM_SIZE, &bytesWritten, NULL);

CHAR Buffer[BUF_SIZE];
WCHAR lineBuffer[BUF_SIZE * 1024]; // Assume that the line does not exceed 1024 
    characters
DWORD nIn, nOut;
INT lineLength = 0;

while (ReadFile(hIn, Buffer, BUF_SIZE, &nIn, NULL) && nIn > 0) {
    if (nIn == 1) {
        printf("Encoding error in the input file\nThe encoding must be UTF-16 LE");
        CloseHandle(hIn);
        CloseHandle(hOut);
        return -1;
    }

    // Check if the current character is a newline character
    if (Buffer[0] == '\r' && Buffer[1] == '\0') {
        // If this is a newline character, write it to the output file
        WriteFile(hOut, lineBuffer, lineLength * sizeof(WCHAR), &nOut, NULL);
        if (lineLength * sizeof(WCHAR) != nOut) {
            printf("Unrecoverable write error: %x\n", GetLastError());
            CloseHandle(hIn);
            CloseHandle(hOut);
            return -1;
        }

        // Add the replacement character at the end of the line
        WriteFile(hOut, &replacement, sizeof(WCHAR), &nOut, NULL);
        if (sizeof(WCHAR) != nOut) {
            printf("Unrecoverable write error: %x\n", GetLastError());
            CloseHandle(hIn);
            CloseHandle(hOut);
            return -1;
        }

        // Reset line length
        lineLength = 0;
        myData->replacementsCount++; // Increment the replacement counter
    }
    else {
        // Save the character to the line buffer
        lineBuffer[lineLength++] = (Buffer[1] << 8) | Buffer[0]; // Convert from UTF-16 
    LE
    }
}

// Write the remaining line if it is not empty
if (lineLength > 0) {
    WriteFile(hOut, lineBuffer, lineLength * sizeof(WCHAR), &nOut, NULL);
    if (lineLength * sizeof(WCHAR) != nOut) {
        printf("Unrecoverable write error: %x\n", GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(hIn);
        CloseHandle(hOut);
        return -1;
    }

           // Add the replacement character at the end of the last line
    WriteFile(hOut, &replacement, sizeof(WCHAR), &nOut, NULL);
    if (sizeof(WCHAR) != nOut) {
        printf("Unrecoverable write error: %x\n", GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(hIn);
        CloseHandle(hOut);
        return -1;
    }
}

CloseHandle(hIn);
CloseHandle(hOut);
wprintf(L"(Thread) Processed file %s with %d replacements.\n", filename, myData- 
 >replacementsCount);
return 0;
 }

 int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
// Set console encoding to UTF-16 LE
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);

// Thread handles
HANDLE hThreads[threads];
// Auxiliary variables
int i;

if (argc < 3) {
    wprintf(L"Usage: laba7.exe filename replacement_char ...\n");
    exit(-1);
}

// Create mutex
hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);

// Get the replacement character from command line arguments
wchar_t replacementChar = (wchar_t)argv[argc - 1][0]; // Take the last argument as the 
 replacement character

   for (i = 0; i < argc - 2; i++) {
    // Fill the data structure
    data[i].num = i;
    swprintf(data[i].file, MAX_PATH, L"%S", argv[i + 1]); // Convert from char to 
    wchar_t
    data[i].replacement = replacementChar; // Set the replacement character
    data[i].replacementsCount = 0; // Initialize the replacement counter

    // Create thread
    hThreads[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, threadfunc, (LPVOID)&data[i], 0, NULL);
    if (hThreads[i] == NULL) {
        wprintf(L"Can't create thread %d!\n", i);
        exit(-i);
    }
    else {
        wprintf(L"(Main) Created thread %d!\n", i);
    }
}

// Close thread handles
for (i = 0; i < argc - 2; i++) {
    // Ensure all threads have finished
    WaitForSingleObject(hThreads[i], INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(hThreads[i]);
}

// Release the mutex
CloseHandle(hMutex);
return 0;
 }

This code should open the file and insert a user-defined character at the end of each line. Next, an output file is created. Everything is fine, substitutions are considered, but when I insert Russian or some other language, some hieroglyphs are inserted at the end of each line. It only works with English. The source file is in utf 16 le bom encoding, as is the output file. Everything should work in this encoding, VisualStudio encoding is multibyte.
When you set a character in the code, everything works, but when you enter it from cmd, nothing works. It feels like during the transfer of data through the stream, they are somehow lost.
How do I make sure that all data remains in utf 16 le bom encoding?

Well ... for starters argv[argc - 1] is a pointer to char. argv[argc - 1][0] can never hold a multibyte character. Don't know if Windows allows for (the extension) int main(int argc, wchar_t **argv) but you need something like that.

For Windows, it's wmain instead of main for wide-character arguments.

Nothing helps, the data is still not being read the way it needs to be.
Because xBF XeF xBF appear in the output file at the very beginning. Some bytes that are commonly used in utf 8 , I can't understand why it doesn't work in utf 16 le bom
